# Music playlist database design

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, database-design, playlist

How to structure tables for songs and playlists?

My thought was to create a table of playlists titles and id's then a playlists songs table that holds the songs unique id and the playlist which it belongs to. The other plan a new table for each playlist and store song information in each table for the playlist.

Would this be a good approach or is creating new tables bad for performance or any other reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about something like this?

Songs:

```
id title length artist_id
```

Artists:

```
id name
```

Playlists:

```
id title user_id
```

Playlists_Songs:

```
playlist_id song_id
```

Users:

```
id name email
```

Comment: thanks for the response, that is basically the layout i have now which I think works great.  A friend of mine had said he'd rather use one table per playlist but that just didn't sound correct to me. Do you know if that approach would work and just be "bad practice" or is it okay to creating and deleting tables like that?

Comment: It is definitely bad practice and much more resource extensive.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of relational design, you need two tables for playlists, one holding the playlistname (key, playlistname), one for the actual playlists (key,playlistkey,trackid)
Table for tracks holding mp3 tag details (key, track title, artist key, album .... Etc)
Table for Artists (key, name, band). You can break it down further applying the principle that you should not duplicate data for instance holding a playlistname in more than one table. By creating views, you knit all this together

However, if you are using android, this database already exists.